# Vuetify - Show tooltip on click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

[image]

I have button that trigger a tooltip when my user clicked `Copy`

```
<v-btn @click="showCopiedText = !showCopiedText; copyHtmlText()">Copy</v-btn>

<v-tooltip v-model="showCopiedText" right>
    <span>Copied!</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

It works but my tool tip kept showing the tip left of my windows instead of next to my button.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `v-btn` should be inside the `v-tooltip`'s `activator` slot, so that the component can position itself around the contents:

1. Move the `v-btn` into the `v-tooltip`'s `activator` slot.
2. In the `v-btn`'s click-handler, use the `slot`'s `on` property to simulate a `mouseenter` to show the tooltip; and `mouseleave` after a timeout to hide it. Make sure to clear the timeout in `beforeDestroy` in case the component is unmounted before the timeout.

```html
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    1️⃣
    <v-btn v-bind="attrs" @click="toClick(on, $event)">Copy</v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>Copied</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

```js
export default {
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearTimeout(this._timerId)
  },
  methods: {
    2️⃣
    toClick({ mouseenter, mouseleave }, e) {
      clearTimeout(this._timerId)
      mouseenter(e)
      this._timerId = setTimeout(() => mouseleave(e), 1000)
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VwydeNQ?editors=101)

Alternatively, you can use a `v-model` on the `v-tooltip` to show/hide the tooltip instead of the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` simulations:

1. Declare a `show` Boolean prop, and use the prop as the `v-tooltip`'s `v-model`.
2. In the `v-btn`'s click-handler, set the prop to `true`, and use a timeout to reset it to `false`. Make sure to clear the timeout in `beforeDestroy` in case the component is unmounted before the timeout.

```html
<v-tooltip bottom v-model="show"> 1️⃣
  <template v-slot:activator="{ attrs }">
    <v-btn v-bind="attrs" @click="showTooltip">Copy</v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>Copied</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: false, 1️⃣
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearTimeout(this._timerId)
  },
  methods: {
    showTooltip() {
      2️⃣
      this.show = true;
      this._timerId = setTimeout(() => this.show = false, 1000)
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/popKbyd)

Comment: Thanks Tony for always helping me on vue.js. Cheers ✨

Answer (score 3):

Here is working demo. Try this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      isShowTooltip: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    hideToolTip(){
      setTimeout(()=>this.isShowTooltip = false, 2000);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="4" sm="6" class="pl-0">
          <v-tooltip
            v-model="isShowTooltip"
            open-on-click
            :open-on-hover="false"
            close-delay='3000'
            right
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                large outlined color="indigo"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                @click="hideToolTip"
              >
              Copy
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>Copied</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From VueJS [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#visibility) a tooltip still needs to be positioned. In this example the tooltip is inside a vueJS grid and is positioned correctly. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I don't understand.... so how do I fix mine to display relatively next to the button that was clicked ?

Comment: With the snippet of the code you provided there isnt much we can see. The docs implement what I think you want. My recommendation is start off the docs example and tweak it to fit your purpose. 

UPDATE 

By the screenshot it seems your tooltip is displaying outside grid where the button copy is. That's as much I can say. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I was at the Link u share. I don’t know how to make it work

Comment: Maybe wait for a more definitive answer. But as I said, tweak the example and cross reference what you have with the code in the docs.